# AWS Lambda not getting invoked for PutObject events from Cross Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge, aws-s3-client

I have a cross account data sharing architecture which is as follows.

Account A (Data Sending Account/ Source Account):

- A glue job that does the cross account copy of S3 objects (PutObject) to Account B

Account B (Data Receiving Account/ Destination Account):

- S3 Bucket  that recieves the S3 objects from Account A.
- S3 Event notification enabled for the above bucket to raise notifcations on Put events.
- A Lambda which recieves the above events and gets invoked to track the objects in a meta table.

What's Working:

Glue job in Account A is able to send the S3 objects to the bucket in Account B. Proper policies and roles have been configured at both ends.

What's not Working:

The Lambda in Account B is not getting invoked for PutObject events from cross account (Account A). I assumed that it must have been an issue with my S3 event notification which invokes my lambda, so I tried to put an object within Account B in the same bucket for which the notifcation is raised and lambda is getting invoked. However the lambda is not getting invoked when the object is put from Account A.

Any help would be appericiated.

Comment: You might be missing the access policy. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-s3-cross-account-function-invoke/

Comment: If I understood everything correctly: The lambda and the bucket lives in account B. If You do the Ingest from Account A to Account B then S3 Bucket from Account B creates a PutEvent, which can trigger the lambda. If this is the actual scenario thet the lambda does not even need any cross-account permissions, because everything happens in Account B. So maybe verify the lambda permissions?